# How do I block a single css file from being loaded with firefox or chrome?

Tags: windows-7, css

I want to be able to block one css file from loading on my system. The site has multiple sheets that I do want to load but it has one hideous theme.css file that I just have to get rid of. I would prefer to use Chrome but FF is ok too. A system wide ban on the file would be ideal. I want to specify a single url that the computer becomes incapable of fetching it. I will then use stylish to create my own replacement. BTW its a SharePoint theme and it has way too many rules to have to override.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use software such as Adblock plus and institute a rule to block it (simply block the URL, just like marking an ad) but note that blocking a CSS file often would mean disturbing the layout of the website which you may or may not want to do.

That way you can use firefox.

Comment: I used Adthwart with Chrome which worked nicely Thanks.